# Is evaluation(detection) on multi gpu possible when data is previously trained on a single gpu?

Tags: python, tensorflow

We are trying to recognize numbers on number plates given pictures of it.
We have trained the data set based on a single gpu.
Is it possible to evaluate the data on multiple gpus without modifying the model?
We use Tensorflow library for training and evaluating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really difficult to help you without any code. 
I can give you an insight. 
To pass from GPU to multi GPU, you have to :

1) Split your data according the number of GPU (be careful of the size, it must be matrix)

2) Build your graph on each gpu with a loop looking like :

```
with tf.variable_scope(tf.get_variable_scope()) as outer_scope:
            for i in enumerate(range(nb_of_GPU)):
                name = 'tower_{}'.format(i)
                with tf.device("/gpu:"+str(i)), tf.name_scope(name):
                    logits = self.build_graph(splitted_inputs[i])
                    batch_loss = self.compute_loss(logits, splitted_labels[i])
                    batch_acc = self.compute_acc(logits, splitted_labels[i])
                    losses.append(batch_loss)
                    accs.append(batch_acc)
                    tf.summary.scalar("loss", batch_loss)
                    gradient = optimizer.compute_gradients(batch_loss)
                    tower_grads.append(gradient)
                    outer_scope.reuse_variables()
        avergage_grads = average_gradients(tower_grads)
        train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(avergage_grads)
```

You also have to change the size of the placeholder for inputs.

So the answer of your question *Is it possible to evaluate the data on multiple gpus without modifying the model?* is **No**.
You will have to change some things.